# Entrance times of a continuous stochastic process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stopping-times

Let $X$ be a continuous stochastic process with index set $\mathbb{R}_+$, and state space $\mathbb{R}$. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a filtration generated by $X$. For fixed $b\geq0$, let $T$ be the time of the first entrance to $[b,\infty]$, that is,
$$T = \inf \{t \in \mathbb{R}_+: X_t\geq b\}.$$
Show that $T$ is a stopping time of $\mathcal{F}$.

My attempt was to write ${T\leq t}$ in terms of $X_t$ but in that case I have an uncountable union. Any suggestions on how to get through this? Can I use rational numbers somehow?

Comment: Simply note that $$\{T\leqslant t\}=\{\exists s\leqslant t,X_s\geqslant b\}=\bigcup_q\{X_{tq}\geqslant b\}$$ where the union is over every rational number $q$ in $[0,1]$. Exercise: This uses *twice* the continuity of the process, how?